# How can I use one variable with another in Vue JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
const n = this.prac
const x = this.oa
console.log(x)
console.log(n[0].x)
```

So n stores data from a JSON file with columns like Organizations, Title etc.
**oa** will have a value given as input by the user. Let's suppose user inputs **Organizations**
I want to print n[0].x i.e n[0].Organizations
but when I do `console.log(n[0].x)` it print undefined
On the other hand `console.log(n[0].Organizations)` works fine.
What am I doing wrong? Can I not use x instead of Organizations?

Comment: `x` is a completely separate variable, so why do you expect in as a property of `n[0]`? Why aren't you just doing `n[0].x = this.oa`?

Comment: Basically, I am creating a graph, for that, I want to take user input and create that graph according to that.
Here **oa** will have value Organizations (input by user), so when I don ```x=this.oa``` x will have the value Organizations, so I was thinking shouldn't ```console.log(n[0].x)``` give the same out put as ```console.log(n[0].Organizations)``` as value of x is Organizations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When attempting to access data from an object with a variable, you can use **bracket notation** instead of **dot notation**.

So for you, you can do

```
const n = this.prac
const x = this.oa
console.log(x)
console.log(n[0][x])
```

Which should result in the value you're looking for.

I found this wonderful answer here [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json/11922384) that gives more details and background on why this works.